# React redux is asking for Provider wrapping in one file but no others

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have an app with a number of files in it using redux with no problem. I have created a new data file with a reducer and selector and registered it with a root reducer.

If I use these commands in one file, it works fine ...

```
import { getSubs } from '../state/subs/selectors';
const subs = useSelector(getSubs);
```

However, if I use them in a different file, I get the run time error

```
Error: could not find react-redux context value; please ensure the component is wrapped in a <Provider>
```

This second file is a child of the one that works. Is that the problem? Does the wrapping need to be direct? If so, is there a work around for this?

Update : the app uses next.js and I am wondering if that has something to do with the issue. Here is where it is wrapped.

```
import { wrapper } from '../state/store';

const App = ({ Component, pageProps }) => (
  <Layout>
    <Component {...pageProps} />
  </Layout>
);

App.propTypes = {
  Component: PropTypes.func,
  pageProps: PropTypes.object,
};

export default wrapper.withRedux(App);
```

Comment: It strange, context values can be spread through all of the child's

Comment: Just to make sure: Your component is not imported and used in a component that is somehow inserted outside the <Provider> component in your app.tsx or whatever file that contains the Provider? Easy mistake to make if for example your app header component lies outside, and at some point you decided to use a Selector in that file as well.

Comment: To my knowledge, everything is a child of the div wrapped by the provider. Somehow, it isn't treated that way though.